# Запретить переинициализацию static переменных после закрытия приложения

Tags: java, android, android-service

В приложении есть небольшой чат на веб-сокетах, после закрытия самого приложения сервис остается работать в фоне для ожидания получения новых сообщений. В этом сервисе я использую статические переменные, хранящиеся в классе самого сервиса. После закрытия приложения на некоторых устройствах статические переменные инициализируются дефолтными значениями. Можно ли каким-то образом этого избежать?

Comment: Что такое "очищается переменная" - известно только Вам.

Comment: Если в процессе работы приложения я присваиваю этим переменным какие-либо значения - то после закрытия приложения эти переменные возвращаются к исходным значениям, как будто бы в процессе работы приложения они и не менялись. А без этих переменных продолжение работы сервиса в принципе бессмысленно.

Comment: Если статическое поле не final - 99% что оно не должно быть статичным. Что именно вы храните в поле, в котором значения меняются когда вы этого не просили?

Comment: мне кажется тут надо выносить логику в сервис, который в отдельном процессе находится.

Comment: У меня там много что хранится, но по большей части это String. Использовать final для всех этих переменных нет возможности, потому что большая часть из них, очевидно, меняется в процессе работы приложения, а потом уже эти значения используются в сервисе.

Comment: Вы зря рассчитываете на то, что сервис будет работать после закрытия приложения! Это когда эмулятор или телефон на шнурке в режиме отладки - всё так радужно! А так система прибьёт Ваш сервис при переходе в doze mode, чтоб он не жрал батарейку.

Comment: Проблема тоже очевидна, и я пытаюсь ее решить. Возможно у Вас есть свое решение?

Comment: Лично я перехватываю событие закрытия сервиса (onTaskRemoved() и onDestroy(), а также метод finalize() в классе сервиса), переопределяя соответствующие методы, где устанавливаю через минуту AlarmManager для перезапуска сервиса. Также есть BroadcastReceiver, выполняющийся после перезагрузки и после изменения статуса подключения к сети.